# Sharepoint - user can log in only from one computer

Tags: claims-based-auth

We are using claims based authentication and observing strange behavior - one user can log in only from one browser. The moment the same user logs in from the second browser his session dies in the first one. Did anyone observe similar behavior? How to fix it and let same user log in from multiple browsers?

Comment: Is this happening in IE or when using IE and chrome or something?

Comment: Thanks, we found an answer - we have 2 sp nodes and what was happening is that 2nd node was not accepting cookie from the 1st.

Comment: Wonderful. It would be great if you can post your finding as a detailed answer to this, so that people having similar issue can find this helpful.